# SPSS and Scikit-learn giving different PCA eigenvectors coefficients

Tags: python, pca, spss, scikit-learn

The Python code used, printed are the eigenvector coefficients and the relative eigenvalues, the data is the same for both SPSS and Python:

```
X = dat[cols]
pca = PCA(n_components=2,svd_solver = 'full').fit(X)
print(pca.components_.T)
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
```

Python Output:

```
[[-0.61573707 -0.12879642]
 [-0.40476782 -0.3582253 ]
 [-0.26925575  0.67811576]
 [-0.37436419  0.53892622]
 [-0.49435177 -0.32373394]]
[0.31112415 0.25145249]
```

SPSS Output:

```
[[0.793 -0.027]
[0.608  -0.510]
[0.276  0.812]
[0.478  0.621]
[0.603  -0.314]]
[0.33332266 0.28082707]
```

I tried applying different normalization methods:

```
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit(X)
X_scaled = scaler.transform(X)
pca = PCA(n_components=2,svd_solver = 'full').fit(X_scaled)

[[-0.82663883 -0.23475242]
 [-0.31202742 -0.28986165]
 [-0.27729367  0.74274876]
 [-0.25778984  0.5187487 ]
 [-0.27560797 -0.20023884]]
[0.34864558 0.24545525]


scaler = preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler().fit(X)
X_scaled = scaler.transform(X)
pca = PCA(n_components=2,svd_solver = 'full').fit(X_scaled)

[[ 0.55296252 -0.70429099]
 [ 0.11899483 -0.31431751]
 [ 0.63331106  0.50543344]
 [ 0.51086644  0.27929861]
 [ 0.13418372 -0.26778354]]
[0.34906865 0.26269499]


scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
X_scaled = scaler.transform(X)
pca = PCA(n_components=2,svd_solver = 'full').fit(X_scaled)

[[-0.60705794 -0.03705608]
 [-0.51335244 -0.37088481]
 [-0.20018055  0.67711926]
 [-0.29857834  0.59942764]
 [-0.48859866 -0.20800795]]
[0.3126145  0.24884053]


scaler = preprocessing.RobustScaler().fit(X)
X_scaled = scaler.transform(X)
pca = PCA(n_components=2,svd_solver = 'full').fit(X_scaled)

[[-0.28720655 -0.51737357]
 [-0.93496554  0.31763895]
 [ 0.00257742 -0.15641986]
 [-0.00360587 -0.32249965]
 [-0.20816385 -0.70919453]]
[0.49561027 0.18208105]
```

I get very different results. Given this I don't feel confident using any of these coefficients. Any ideas? Assuming the coefficients obtained by SPSS are the most correct how could I replicate them? and are they?

Comment: You must present the data, for people to try it. And also the spss syntax.